# Django: How do I extend the same functionality to many views?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, template-inheritance

I have a parent template that I'm using in many parts of the site, called `base.html`. This template holds a lot of functional components, such as buttons that trigger different forms (inside modal windows) allowing users to upload different kinds of content, etc. I want users to be able to click these buttons from almost any part of the site (from all the templates that inherit from `base.html`).

I've written a view that handles the main page of the site, `HomeView` (it renders `homepage.html`, which inherits from `base.html`). I've written a bunch of functionality into this view, which handles all the uploads.

Since many templates are going to inherit from `base.html`, and therefore have all that same functionality, do I have to copy-and-paste the hundreds of lines of code from the `HomeView` into the views that render all the other pages??

There's got to be a better way, right?

How do I make sure that the functionality in a parent base template holds true for all views which call child templates that inherit from this base template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put all the lines of code from `HomeView` in a separate function let be `func` 
and have `func` return a dictionary containing all context variables needed 
and call it whenever needed so your `HomeView` would look like this:

```
def HomeView(request):
  dict = func(request)
  ... # rest of code that is not common with other views
```

and your `func` would look like:

```
def func(request):
  #all repeated code
  #put all needed variables in a dictionary and return it
  dict = {'var1': 4, 'var2': "a String" ...}
  return dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe separating out your upload related functionality into separate views will be better way to go about it. That way all your templates (inheriting from `base.html`) will refer to appropriate view for uploads.

You can use `HTTP_REFERER` header to redirect to appropriate page from the upload views.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `TemplateResponse` instead of `HttpResponse` in `home_view`. This way you will be able to update context and switch template on the response.
2. Call `home_view` inside other views like this:

   ```
   from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

   def other_view( request ):

       #produce other_context

       t = home_view( request )
       t.context.update( other_context )
       t.template = 'other_template.html'
       return t
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can render many templates in just one view by requiring unique value in each or use request session.

Answer (score 0):

Load the functionality part with ajax on your base.html.

That way you have a view_method that deals exclusively with those funcionalities.